# Error rendering Force.com Canvas application

Tags: salesforce

I had developed an app using Canvas. While loading Canvas, it shows an error like,

> Oops, there was an error rendering Force.com Canvas application [Hello World].Your browsing session has ended or is invalid. Please re-login to Salesforce.com again.

The app was working fine before. But now it is frequently showing this error. But once I clear the browser cache and then try again, it works well for a while.  After some time it shows the same error.

The Access Method in the Canvas App Settings is Signed Request (POST)

The visual force page looks like,

```
<apex:page controller="CanvasController">
..
..
<apex:canvasApp id="canvasFrame" applicationName="HelloWorld" parameters="{!parameters}" width="100%"/>
..
..
```

And the Controller looks like

```
public class CanvasController{
    public string parameters{get;set;}
    public Contact contactRecord;
    ...
    …
    public void someMethod(){
        ..
        contactRecord = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
        parameters = JSON.serialize(contactRecord);
    }
}
```

Please help me if you have any suggestion. Thanks in advance.